# I can't find apk release file for Play Store

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I want to release 2nd android app in Play Market.
For release need apk file
Firstly, I go to Genereate Signed Bundle or APK, there I choice android.jks file from my 1st app and key alias.
I get message :

```
App bundle(s) generated successfully: 
Module 'app': locate or analyze the app bundle.
```

When i click locate i can't find apk file

Comment: just click locate you will find the path...

Comment: unfortunally, there no apk file

Comment: Please go to your Project folder. Then go to app folder. There will be a release folder. Release apk will be there in that folder.

Comment: @Bekzhan have you got it?

Comment: I found only **app.aab** file

Answer (score 5):

see you are generating android app bundle as per below message

```
App bundle(s) generated successfully: 
Module 'app': locate or analyze the app bundle.
```

so there should be .aab file instead of apk

if you are generating app bundle you can find it under

> app>build>outputs>release>your_app_name.aab

to generate apk you must follow these steps

> build>generate singed bundle/apk > select apk > then proceed

Answer (score 3):

Click on locate please > release > app-release.apk

There you go!!

Comment: I found only app.aab file

Comment: That's your android app bundle file.

Answer (score 3):

I think you made a mistake while generating Signed APk. You have to select 'APK' option in the first dialog appears while generating Signed APk.

Then Please go to your Project folder. Then go to app folder. There will be a release folder. Release apk will be there in that folder